# How to get data ordered by month

Tags: sql, oracle, plsqldeveloper

I could not get the data in an ordered format like APR, MAY, JUNE, JULY. I want to display data ordered by month.

This is what I'm currently doing:

```
  SELECT (TO_CHAR (TRUNC (exec_end), 'DD-MON-YY'))
    FROM tbl_dumps
   WHERE exec_end >= TO_DATE (SYSDATE - 90)
GROUP BY TO_CHAR (TRUNC (exec_end), 'DD-MON-YY'),
         TO_CHAR (TRUNC (exec_end), 'MON')
ORDER BY (TO_CHAR (TRUNC (exec_end), 'MON')) DESC
```

Below is the current OUTPUT:

```
01-MAY-18,
02-MAY-18,
03-MAY-18,
31-MAY-18,
O1-JUN-18,
02-JUN-18,
03-JUN-18,
04-JUN-18,
01-JUL-18,
02-JUL-18,
03-JUL-18,
26-APR-18,
27-APR-18,
28-APR-18.
```

This is how I want my OUTPUT:

```
26-APR-18,
27-APR-18,
28-APR-18,
01-MAY-18,
02-MAY-18,
03-MAY-18,
31-MAY-18,
O1-JUN-18,
02-JUN-18,
03-JUN-18,
04-JUN-18,
01-JUL-18,
02-JUL-18,
03-JUL-18.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide more details on exactly what you're trying to do, and what isn't working. Please also take the time to look at this page and understand what makes a good question here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Some sample data would help a lot here.

Comment: `TO_CHAR(..., 'MON')` returns the first three letters of the month *name* as a string - you are therefore sorting the results in reverse alphabetical order of month name. You could instead use `order by TRUNC(exec_end, 'MON')` which means it will be sorted by month.

Comment: p.s. I don't know why you would put `DESC` if you want them sorted in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you might need

```
select to_char(exec_end, 'dd-mon-yy')
from tbl_dumps
where exec_end >= trunc(sysdate) - 90
order by to_char(exec_end, 'mm')
```

Also, as `sysdate - 90` looks like "3 months ago", consider using `add_months(sysdate, -3)` instead.